# struct types / function call

Tags: c, function, struct

I'm working on a program and can't understand the compiler errors.

```
arrays.c:12:21: error: flexible array member not at end of struct
arrays.c: In function 'insert':
arrays.c:22:4: warning: statement with no effect
```

I know these are very simple things, but I cant fix them. I am not sure if I my insert function is correct. Can anyone please help me? Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define AMOUNT 7




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a student project. Are you trying make us do your homework?

Comment: not really, just trying to understand what my problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A struct member declared with empty square brackets `[]` is called a *flexible array member*. This is explained in the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/), question 2.6 (scroll all the way to the bottom). A flexible array member may appear only as the last declared member of a struct, which is what your compiler is complaining about.

But moving it to the end of the struct is not the best solution; you probably don't want to use a flexible array member at all. (You could, but it introduces unnecessary complexity.)

As dasblinkenlight says, you can make the `name` member a pointer:

```
struct person {
    char *name;
    int age;
};
```

`name` would then point to a string representing the person's name -- which means you'll need to allocate memory to hold the string.

Or you can make `name` an array of `char`, with a fixed maximum size:

```
#define MAX_NAME 50
struct person {
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    int age;
};
```

You can then use the `strcpy` function to copy a value into `name` -- being careful that you don't try to copy more than `MAX_NAME` bytes.

In your `insert` function, these statements:

```
people[nextcell].names;
people[nextcell].ages;
```

were presumably intended to initialize the `names` and `ages` members (better names: `name` and `age`), but in fact they do nothing; they refer to those members, but they don't do anything with them.  For `age`, you can simply assign the value of the `age` parameter (which you're currently ignoring) to the `age` member:

```
people[nextcell].age = age;
```

The way to assign a value to `name` depends on whether you decide to define it as a pointer or as an array.